# issue in changing value of input field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<p>This is a basic tag input: 
    <input id="tag1" value="alpha,beta,gamma" />
</p>
</div>
<textarea id="tagdetect"></textarea>
```

**script**

```
$("#tagdetect").live("keydown",function(){

    var textTyped=$("#tagdetect").val();
    var text=textTyped.split(" ");
    for(i=0;i<text.length;i++){

        if(text[i]=="sql"||text[i]=="html"||text[i]=="java"){

            $("#tag1").val()=text[i];
        }
    }
});
```

**what i am trying to achieve**

I am trying to add tags(ie values) in that input field when certain keywords are detected

**Working version**

http://jsfiddle.net/7aDak/4839/

Comment: .live is deprecated. use .on

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your jQuery syntax.

Change the following line

```
$("#tag1").val()=text[i];
```

To this:

```
$("#tag1").val(text[i]);
```

Comment: Try changing `.live("keydown"` to `.on("keyup"`. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p223B/2/. Keyup will fire as soon as the user finishes entering the string. Keydown fires the function each time you press a key, so you would press a key once more, such as return, for keydown to work.

Comment: With that tagsInput function, it's hiding the #tag1 input. you'll need to use inspector or firebug to unhide. Not sure what else you're trying to do here, but the syntax error was the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

to set the value you should use:

```
 $("#tag1").val(text[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Function .val() need to have parameters of what you want to append:

```
var value = $("#tag1").val();
$("#tag1").val(value + text[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more elegant apart from fixing your errors - assuming you want all the tags in the field

```
var types = ["sql","html","java"];

$("#tagdetect").on("keydown",function(){

  var textTyped=$("#tagdetect").val();
  var text=textTyped.split(" ");
  $.each(text,function(_,txt) {
    if ($.inArray(txt,types)!=-1) $("#tag1").append(txt+" ");
  });
});
```